# Debugging setup of cgit using apache 2.4 on my ubuntu 18.04 vps

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, git

**Background**

I want to setup cgit using apache 2.4 on my ubuntu 18.04 vps. I already have the git server running with ssh access for myself. But I also want to have a web viewer for my repos.

**Debug Process**

When I visit my subdomain (git.example.com), I get a not found error. The apache
error log shows no errors. The apache access log shows the 404 status. This makes
me think apache is unable to see the files. However, the files exist and appear
to allow apache's www-data user to read and write (execute, as needed).

**Question**

I am unsure how to proceed debugging this issue.

**Permissions**

```
user@vps ~$ sudo -u www-data ls -l /home/www-data/cgit
total 1148
-rwxrwsr-x 1 www-data gitusers 1140464 Jul 26 03:08 cgit.cgi
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data gitusers   14237 Jul 26 03:08 cgit.css
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data gitusers    1278 Jul 26 03:08 cgit.png
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data gitusers    1078 Jul 26 03:08 favicon.ico
drwxrwsr-x 3 www-data gitusers    4096 Jul 26 03:08 filters
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data gitusers      47 Jul 26 03:08 robots.txt
```

**Error log**

```
No error
```

**Access log**

```
[ip address] - - [utc timestamp] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 3950 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
```

**Browser displays**

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at git.example.com Port 443
```

**VirtualHost file**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    #======================================================================#
    # Basic admin setings                                                  #
    #======================================================================#

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName git.example.com
    ServerAlias www.git.example.com
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #======================================================================#
    # cgit settings                                                        #
    #======================================================================#

    DocumentRoot /home/www-data/cgit
    SetEnv CGIT_CONFIG  /home/www-data/cgit/cgitrc
    Alias /cgit.css     /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.css
    Alias /cgit.png     /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.png
    Alias /favicon.ico  /home/www-data/cgit/favicon.ico
    Alias /robots.txt   /home/www-data/cgit/robots.txt
    Alias /             /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.cgi/

    <Directory /home/www-data/cgit>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
      DirectoryIndex cgit.cgi
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*\.git(|(/(?!(HEAD|info|objects|refs|git-(upload|receive)-pack)).*)))?$ /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.cgi/$1
    Alias /cgit-css /home/www-data/cgit/

    #======================================================================#
    # Use Git's Smart HTTP Protocol                                        #
    #======================================================================#

    # Allow exporting of all repos. To choose which repos to allow exporting of,
    # comment this out and use touch /path/to/repo.git/git-daemon-export-ok
    # for each exportable repo.
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

    # Set location of git repos.
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git

    # Make writes require authentication via apache gitusers password file.
    <Files "git-http-backend">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "git.example.com Git Repo Push Access"
        AuthUserFile /home/git/gitusers
        Require valid-user
    </Files>
    #Alternatives to the require expr above
    ScriptAliasMatch "^/(.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs))$" /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1
    ScriptAliasMatch "^/(.*\.git/git-(upload|receive)-pack)$" /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

    #======================================================================#
    # SSL configuration                                                    #
    #======================================================================#

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite TLSv1.2:RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5
    SSLCompression off
    TraceEnable Off
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. Looks like the major issue was the presence of the `DirectoryIndex` directive. Otherwise I just moved some directives around. Below is the corrected cgit section.

```
#======================================================================#
# cgit settings                                                        #
#======================================================================#

# Set the root location of cgit files.
# With the aliases used as below, cgit expects the left alias path in its
# cgitrc file.
DocumentRoot /home/www-data/cgit/

# Set the location of the cgit config file.
SetEnv CGIT_CONFIG  /home/www-data/cgit/cgitrc

# Set aliases for cleaner urls.
Alias /cgit.css     /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.css
Alias /cgit.png     /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.png
Alias /favicon.ico  /home/www-data/cgit/favicon.ico
Alias /robots.txt   /home/www-data/cgit/robots.txt
Alias /cgit-css     /home/www-data/cgit
ScriptAlias /       /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.cgi/

# Set directory options for the directory holding cgit files.
<Directory /home/www-data/cgit>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.git(|(/(?!(HEAD|info|objects|refs|git-upload-pack)).*)))?$ /home/www-data/cgit/cgit.cgi/$1
```

Note that I also removed the receive pack option since I only want to allow push via ssh, but cloning via https and ssh are ok.